# Move Social Icons from Header to Content Area

Tags: html

I Move Social Icons from Header to Content Area

Comment: what do you need to change ?? social icons images??

Comment: @AjeshVC  i just want to delete that space and bring it down in content in line with heading "about"

Comment: Have you checked header.php i think it may help u

Comment: yes i did but nothing their

Comment: Are u added this as a separate plugin or with theme??

Comment: Its Mantra theme of wordpress or for any wordpress theme u  can pic

Comment: @Gunaseelan  checked that too

Comment: @Gunaseelan i  when inspect need to find that code in theme as shown in image link..https://wordpress.org/themes/mantra

Comment: @Gunaseelan those social icons keeps a strip of space under menu i need to pull it down to content section.i can do it with inspect on page but where to edit in theme file

Comment: So you want to move the social icons the header section to the content section. Am I right?

Comment: @Gunaseelan position remains same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part of header.php

```
<div id="main">
<div  id="forbottom" >
    <?php cryout_forbottom_hook(); ?> /*Remove this hook*/

    <div style="clear:both;"> </div>

    <?php cryout_breadcrumbs_hook();?>
```

Since you want to display social share icons in the content area, add it to page.php

```
<section id="container">
  <?php cryout_forbottom_hook(); ?> /* Add the hook here to display social icons */
    <div id="content" role="main">
        <?php cryout_before_content_hook(); ?>
        <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'page'); ?>
        <?php cryout_after_content_hook(); ?>
        </div><!-- #content -->
        <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
</section><!-- #container -->
    <?php } // else
     get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.excellent but if u can please tell how did you find did

Comment: It is not a hard thing to find. You can find once you got experience in WordPress. By the way don't forget to accept the answer and upvote.